# Ruby Countdown loop Learn Lab

Tags: ruby, while-loop

I am currently working on a lab to create a countdown timer using a while loop and the subtract/assign operator. So far I have the loop counting 10 and breaking to 0 and printing my string "Happy New Year". I am not sure why it isn't iterating from 10 down to 0. Link to lab and code below https://learn.co/tracks/online-software-engineering-structured/procedural-ruby/looping/countdown-to-midnight-lab

```
number = 10
 while number > 0
   puts "#{number} SECOND(S)!"
   number -= 1
 break if n <= 0
 puts "HAPPY NEW YEAR!"  
end
end
```

Comment: You really should indent your code properly. Then you'd also see the problems quicker. You always decrease the indentation level at an `end` statement. If two `end` statements are on the same level of indentation (like you have here in your code) then you probably did something wrong. Also if the indentation is decreasing without an `end` statement close by (like it does in your code), then you also probably did something wrong.

Answer (score 1):

- There is one `end` too much. Proper indentation could have told you that.
- `puts "HAPPY NEW YEAR!"` should probably be the last line, out of the loop (and probably without the `puts`).
- `n` should be `number`

The task is in the form of a method which returns a string . `puts` however returns `nil`.